# C++ memory and design question on small project

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-management, c++14

I try to create a small library to listen for multiple mice on MAC and PC. (right now MAC)

I have started something simple that does not work ATM. Since I am a noob in C++ I wanted to ask the community for help in this matter. How should I design it in code? I wanted to use smart pointers here is my code, feedl free to download it:

Github:
[Open Source Project](https://github.com/rufreakde/usb-multimouse-grabber)

Everything in one file:

#### Device Class

```
class Device;

class Device {

public:
Device(){
    std::cout << "###### Create Device - Empty" << std::endl;

    this->x_previous = 0;
    this->y_previous = 0;
    this->x_current = 0;
    this->y_current = 0;
}

Device( size_t _deviceID, std::string _device_name){
    std::cout << "###### Create Device - 0.0/0.0" << std::endl;

    this->device_id = std::make_shared<size_t>(_deviceID);
    this->device_name = std::make_shared<std::string>(_device_name);

    this->x_previous = 0;
    this->y_previous = 0;
    this->x_current = 0;
    this->y_current = 0;
}

Device(size_t _deviceID, std::string _device_name, float _xStart, float _yStart){
    std::cout << "###### Create Device - " << _xStart << "/" << _yStart << std::endl;
    this->device_id = std::make_shared<size_t>(_deviceID);
    this->device_name = std::make_shared<std::string>(_device_name);

    this->x_previous = _xStart;
    this->y_previous = _yStart;
    this->x_current = _xStart;
    this->y_current = _yStart;
}

~Device(){
    std::cout << "###### Destroyed Device" << std::endl;
}

const size_t getId () const{
    return (size_t)this->device_id.get();
};
const std::string getName() const{
    return "Not Implementet yet"; //this->device_name.get() does not work because of std::basic_string wtf?
};

const float getDeltaX() const{
    return x_previous - x_current;
};
const float getDeltaY() const{
    return y_previous - y_current;
};

private:
std::shared_ptr<size_t> device_id;
std::shared_ptr<std::string> device_name;

float x_previous;
float y_previous;

float x_current;
float y_current;

};
```

#### Devices Class

```
class Devices{

public:
Devices(){
    std::cout << "###### Created Empty Devices List" << std::endl;
    this->list = std::unique_ptr<std::list<Device> >();
}

explicit Devices(std::unique_ptr<std::list<Device> > _list){
    std::cout << "###### Created Moved Devices List" << std::endl;
    this->list = std::move(_list);
}

~Devices(){
    std::cout << "###### Destroyed Devices List" << std::endl;
}

std::unique_ptr<std::list<Device> > list;

void getDevicesArray() {

    CFMutableDictionaryRef usb_dictionary;
    io_iterator_t io_device_iterator;
    kern_return_t assembler_kernel_return_value;
    io_service_t device_id;

    // set up a matching dictionary for the class
    usb_dictionary = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);
    if (usb_dictionary == NULL) {
        std::cout << "failed to fetch USB dictionary" << std::endl;
        return; // still empty
    }

    // Now we have a dictionary, get an iterator.
    assembler_kernel_return_value = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, usb_dictionary, &io_device_iterator);
    if (assembler_kernel_return_value != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "failed to get a kern_return" << std::endl;
        return; // still empty
    }

    io_name_t device_name = "unkown device";
    device_id = IOIteratorNext(io_device_iterator); // getting first device

    while (device_id) {

        device_id = IOIteratorNext(io_device_iterator); //set id type: io_service_t
        IORegistryEntryGetName(device_id, device_name); //set name type: io_name_t

        this->list.get()->push_back(Device(device_id, device_name));
    }

    //Done, release the iterator
    IOObjectRelease(io_device_iterator);
}

void printDeviceIDs(){

    for (auto const& device : *this->list.get()) {
        std::cout << "#" << device.getId() <<  std::endl;
        std::cout << "| name: " << "\t" << device.getName() <<  std::endl;
        std::cout << "#-----------------------------------------------#" << std::endl;
    }
}
};
```

#### main

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
std::shared_ptr<Devices> devices;

devices->printDeviceIDs();
devices->getDevicesArray();
devices->printDeviceIDs();
}
```

Someone knows of a good pattern for that?
Also maybe I use smart pointers completely wrong?
Also the iOKit library is from 1985 or something so it is not very descriptive...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C and C++ are completely different. Please try to only use relevant tags.

Comment: I just want to know if I go into the right direction and use C++ as it is intended to be used :)

The code does not work and I think i have miss-understood how you handle memory in such cases in c++?

Comment: @Thomas Jager But the IOKit from MACis C. So it is C used in C++ right?

Comment: @MaxLanghof aw didn't see that I guess you are right thanks i will post it there!

Comment: The code you have above is not C (C doesn't have classes for instance). If you need help fixing your code, please describe the problem you're having. As stated, it looks like you're asking for design guidance - without being way more specific, this is too broad for Stack Overflow. (And off-topic for codereview.se if the code doesn't work.)

Comment: If you want help with the "does not work" part then you absolutely must include a detailed description of _how_ it doesn't work. What did you expect to happen? What happened? Were there any errors (if so, post the **full** error message)? Otherwise the odds that somebody will sit down to guess your problem and fix your code is extremely low.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<std::list<Device> > list;`, you probably don't want `unique_ptr` here, `std::list<Device> list;` should suffice.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Sorry I already posted it in code Review now! And the problem why it does not work is a failure thrown in:
memory:
  _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
  pointer get() const _NOEXCEPT {
    return __ptr_.first();
  }

As I stated above I was not aware that if you use C MAC OS libraries in C++ you cant use C as tag? So tag is removed and code is posted on CodeReview!

This post can be removed...

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Devices> devices;

devices->printDeviceIDs();` You deference `nullptr`, you probably just need `Devices devices;

devices.printDeviceIDs();`

Comment: @Jarod42 ah you mean in the main? Thanks.

Comment: @MaxLanghof "I have started something simple that does not work ATM." **does not work**. Code Review only accepts code which works, as indicated by [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review, in the process of getting closed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/202814/52915)

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `this->` notation.  You can access members directly, in a class method.

Comment: @Mast I did not tell the author to go to codereview, I just pointed out that the site exists and that it **might** be more suited **if** there was no concrete problem (which the question was/is lacking). I'm sorry that the asker was overzealous about making another post (while ignoring any automatic and manual advice - see Mat's comment) but please do not blame me for it.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I wasn't blaming anyone, just pointing out that a recommendation to CR was not appropriate. That's ok. It happens. We'll clean it up over there. Not blaming anyone for anything.

Comment: @Mast Ok, sorry for misinterpreting your comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other users this is more of a review rather than a error code question;
being that said the only thing I can find is the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::list<Device> > list;
```

you should change that to the following:

```
std::list<Device> list;
```

and on your main

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
std::shared_ptr<Devices> devices;

devices->printDeviceIDs();
devices->getDevicesArray();
devices->printDeviceIDs();
```

}
should probably only suffice to use:

```
Devices devices; devices.printDeviceIDs();
```

Comment: thanks code is now running I updated it on GitHub. It was a problem with my pointer overload.